# Android - Button disappear from the layout when it has transparent background

Tags: android, button, colors, transparency

I have following Table in my Android app. Everything works, except the last button - about me. When I set background to transparent color - it is not beign display on my device (however, it is visible on the graphical view of the layout in the eclipse. By "not display" I mean, that it is not on the screen - on its place its "next". If I remove android:background from the last button - it comes back to device. Whats wrong?

```
                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/buttonShare"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:onClick="shareIt"
                        android:src="@drawable/social_share" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:onClick="prevImage"
                        android:src="@drawable/navigation_previous_item" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:src="@drawable/navigation_accept" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/buttonAbout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:onClick="showAbout"
                        android:src="@drawable/action_about" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/buttonForward"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:onClick="nextImage"
                        android:src="@drawable/navigation_next_item" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/buttonAbout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:onClick="showAbout"
                        android:src="@drawable/action_about" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
```

Part of my color resource is like below:

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

I just loaded overwrited action_about.png picture with new one. Now, the button appears - but it shows old png, about, not the new one. What is going on?

Comment: right click your project in the package explorer and press "Clean Project" Sometimes the resources get stuck on the old versions, cleaning them usually fixes it.

Comment: I do not see Clean Project option.Version: Indigo Service Release 1

Comment: hmm, maybe the removed it from the context menu. If you select the project in the Package Explorer and then click on "Project" at the top do you have a `clean...` option in there?

Comment: No... I found it in source/clean, but it didnt help.

Comment: its not there at all? or it is there but grayed out? I cannot find Indigo sr1 download, but I downloaded sr2 and it is there under project (see edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to set the background to transparent? Do you just want a button that does not have the device default button "frame" and instead has only your action_about drawable? If so you can do that with a normal Button instead of ImageButton like so:

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/buttonAbout"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/action_about"
  android:onClick="showAbout"/>
```

**EDIT:** Also note that you have the buttonAbout element twice in your layout, it is at the bottom, and 3 from the bottom.

**EDIT 2:** Do you not have a `clean...` option at all under the `Project` menu at the top? or is it just grayed out?

I downloaded Eclipse Indigo sr2 (I can't find link on the site for sr1) and It is there for me.
[image]

Comment: Yes, I fixed twiced buttonAbout - it was just experiment to check if button will show in different location.

Comment: Honestly - I lost control on the project yesterday (not updating resources made me headache and I felt asleep at 4:00am ;). On morning I found option which you mentioned and seems it works now. Seems - I am not sure. But I appreciate your effort in helping.